# prove that there exists a unique number x $\in$ R such that $f(x) =x$

Tags: real-analysis

The assumptions that are given in the statement $$f: R\mapsto R$$ and continuous and decreasing.

me and my friend are doing this problem, we have attempted the following:

$f(x) = x$, $c = 0$, c:= a unique point, $f(c) = 0$, therefore we have found a unique point for any general function that passes through the origin.

We also have thought that this maybe flawed because it seems fishy to make such a statement.

we wondered if we can use $\epsilon$, $\delta$ to prove that for some c we can obtain our answer.

we have been sitting with this problem for days now and we also concluded that maybe we could use some type of inverse function.

Should we consider a random function? Should we consider any numbers? Should we make up our own assumptions? was our intial approach correct? Are there any adjustments to our above approach that can improve our rigor?

thanks for any comments or suggestions in advance.

Comment: Existence: Let $g(x)=x-f(x)$. It will come down to showing that $g(x)$ is negative somewhere, positive somewhere, so by the Intermediate Value Theorem $0$ somewhere. Uniqueness: This will be straightforward.

Comment: Also, my friend was saying to it prove by contradiction, i.e. there is another other unique point that exist.

Comment: That's OK for proving uniqueness, for showing that if there is at least one, there is only one. It is existence that requires the IVT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $f(x)$ is decreasing either $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)$ exists or $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to -\infty$. Thus $g(x) = (f(x) - x) \to \infty$ as $x \to -\infty$. Similarly $g(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Hence there are numbers $a, b$ with $a < b$ such that $g(a) > 0, g(b) < 0$ and therefore by intermediate value property of continuous functions there is a $c \in (a, b)$ such that $g(c) = 0$ i.e. $f(c) = c$.

Suppose that there are two values $c, d$ such that $c < d$ and $f(c) = c, f(d) = d$. Then $0 < d - c = f(d) - f(c)$ i.e $f(c) < f(d)$. This is contrary to the assumption that $f$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that $f(x)$ is a bijective function. That is both surjective and injective.

Comment: $f$ is not guaranteed to be a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (example $f(x) = -\arctan(x)$), but $f$ will definitely be a bijection from its domain $\mathbb{R}$ to its range.

Comment: $f(x)=x$, is the function what we are talking about.

Comment: The question is not about a specific function $f(x) = x$, but rather that if $f(x)$ is any function which is continuous and decreasing on all $\mathbb{R}$ then there is a point $c$ such that $f(c) = c$ and this $c$ is unique.

Comment: If the function is not bijective either at the domain or co domain there is either a missing point or more than one point as a solution in general. If the function is monotone it doesn't guarantee that the solution is unique. It only guarrantees that there exists a solution. If the domain is whole real numbers, then the function is not necessarily bijective but there exists a point $c$ for which $f(c)$ is unique.

Comment: If you check my answer you will find that bijection is not needed to show uniqueness of 'c'.

Comment: I don't need to check it. As I told you my post was for $f(x)$ and my following comments are in the same direction as what you have said.